# To wear tsisit (worn under shirts),

Tags: halacha, minhag, tallit-katan

To wear tsisit (worn under shirts), Is it halacha, custom, minhag.  do we have to wear them?

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1705/759

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree, but I think that this question is clearer. Maybe we should close the other as a duplicate of this

Answer (score 2):

The Shulchan Aruch HaRav writes in Orach Chaim ([17:1](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh1/4/24/1.htm))

> אף על פי שאין אדם חייב לקנות טלית בת ד' כנפות כדי שיתחייב בציצית אלא דוקא אם רוצה להתלבש בטלית בת ד' כנפות חייב להטיל בה ציצית מכל מקום טוב ונכון להיות כל אדם זהיר וזריז ללבוש טלית מצוייצת כל היום כדי שיזכור המצות בכל רגע דוגמא לדבר כאדם המזהיר לחבירו על ענין אחד שקושר קשר באזורו כדי שיזכרנו ועל כן יש בציצית ה' קשרים כנגד ה' חומשי תורה וד' כנפות כדי שלכל צד שיפנה יזכור המצות:
>
> Even though a person is not obligated to buy a four cornered garment to put on Tzitzis, but only if he wants to wear a four cornered garment he has to put on Tzitzis. Nonetheless it's appropriate for everyone who is careful [in Miztvos] to wear Tzitzis the whole day to remember the Mitzvos every minute.

The Lubavitcher Rebbe also writes ([Igros Kodesh 8:2619](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/ig/8/2619))

> ובמה שהעיר בענין מצות ציצית אם מקיים המצוה בכל שעה שמלובש בציצית או רק בשעה ראשונה וע"ד נטילת לולב.
>
> הנה מובן הדבר גם ממה שנאמר וראיתם אותו וזכרתם, וכמו שהזכירה בכל עת מצוה היא הרי גם סיבתה היא הראי' כן הוא, ומפורש הדבר בראשונים בספר היראה לרבנו יונה קרוב לתחלתו שכותב וז"ל: עיקר מצות ציצית ללבשו תמיד (כן הוא גירסת הגר"א בביאורו לשו"ע או"ח ריש סימן כ"ד וכן הוא גם דעתו של הגר"א, ראה שם).
>
> ובפסקי דינים לאדמו"ר הצמח צדק או"ח סי' ב' ס"ק ז' משמע דעתו שבכל שעה זהו מצוה דאורייתא (ולא רק הידור דרבנן), וראה ג"כ בפירוש האבן עזרא במדבר ט"ו ל"ט שגם שם מוכח כן.

The Rebbe writes there that the Tzemach Tzedek holds that "every hour" one fulfills the biblical commandment of wearing Tzitzis.

So it appears that while there is no technical obligation to make oneself obligated in the mitzva of Tzitzis, every moment one *does* wear it one fulfills a biblical mitzva.

Comment: Are there no pre-lubavitch sources to be found on this topic? There are no gemaras in menachos? No rambams? Etc..? This answer hardly encompasses the gamut of halachic opinions